snapcraft: How can I have snapname-appname rather than snapname.appname
When publishing multiple apps inside one snap, snapcraft prefixes the appname with "snapname." so the end user appears to see an executable name of "snapname.appname"
My snap is a collection of 7 cli utilities. all with a common prefix, let say "snapname".
but their names are:
snapname-appname
using a minus/dash instead of a period separator, which is much more common in linux cli utilities.
my utilities will also be published via .deb and .rpm etc, so I would like the naming to be consistent as otherwise the documentation will be confusing.
Is there any way around the apparently fixed prefixing scheme with the period?

You want an alias. You can create them manually, but that's not really want you want: you want aliases to which your users have access. In that case, you need to request them by creating a new post in the store-requests category of the forum. Why? To quote the above link:

As there is no guarantee that an alias is going to be unique, and potential conflicts create a minor inconvenience, a snap’s default aliases are only enabled after a simple public review process.
The same review process also ensures that any default commands exposed by a snap are either named after the snap or, when different, reviewed to ensure the alias is relevant within the context of the application. This helps maintain a sane shared namespace for everyone.


Thanks, I had stumbled across that concept, and thought that was the only way.
I also need to get classic confinement approved. Which I believe happens in the same place?

That's correct, although please make two separate requests. You might want to start with the classic one, since that's a little harder to get.
